# graphql get query shows this error "variables are not allowed in scalars"

Tags: graphql, hasura

query describeNotesByNameSpaace($id:bigint!) {
notes(where: {object_meta: {_contains: {owner_references: [{uid:$id}]}}}) {
id
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
query describeNotesByNameSpace($jsonFilter: jsonb) {
  notes(where: {object_meta: {_contains: $jsonFilter}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

And query variable is

```
{
  "jsonFilter": {
    "owner_references": [
        {
            "uid": "1719430910876008448"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.